# Subtle meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Read the following sentence

> She is not subtle about it.

What does subtle mean here? According to me, she isn't trying to hide something or behaving in a direct way so the reality is really known, is that what it means?

Comment: There isn't enough context to answer this question. The only answer that could be given is the dictionary definition of "subtle". Take a look at the [help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a great question.

Comment: You haven't given any context, so the exact meaning isn't "fixed". But most likely you'd encounter this in a context where it's actually "facetious understatement" - true meaning: ***She's outrageously blunt-spoken**!*

Comment: You haven't even told us what "it" is – she is not subtle about _what?_

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with the comments on the original question, I would have to agree that there isn't enough context.

In any case, *subtle* means: "making use of clever and indirect methods to achieve something."

Given that definition I would assume that 'she' is not trying to be clever or sneaky to achieve anything, and that her motives are in the open and easily guessed.